# When loading 5000 or above entries in a Dropdown, it is taking time to load to few seconds

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="row invoice-info">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 invoice-col">
                      <b>To,</b>
                      <address>
                        <select name="customer_id" readonly id="customer_id" title="Select Customer" class="form-control select2" required="">
                          <?php echo $customer_options; ?>
                        </select><br>
                        <b>Address:</b><span id="customer_address"></span><br>
                        <b>Phone:</b> <span id="customer_phone"></span><br>
                        <b>Email:</b> <span id="customer_email"></span>
                      </address>
                    </div>
</div>
```

When loading 5000 or above entries in a Dropdown, it is taking time to load to few seconds. I want to make it quick.

Comment: I think you need to figure out a different way of doing it (perhaps an autocomplete?) because trying to **use** a dropdown with over 5000 values would be next to impossible.

Comment: Agreed. Perhaps a datalist would work better, but some sort of JavaScript autocomplete is probably best

Comment: Hi , i have autocomplete="off" in the form. It does not solve the problem

Comment: I am able to speed up the dropdown when i removed the bootstrap class:   class="form-control select2"...

Answer (score 0):

As you are searching name, You can add additional select box for alphabet selection and then make a ajax call for search result with name starting with selected alphabet...

e.g.

```
<select name='alphabet_select" >
   <option value="">Select</option> 
   <option value="A">A</option>
   <option value="B">B</option>
   <option value="C">C</option>
   .....
   <option value="Z">Z</option>
</select>
```

After selecting alphabet, make ajax call and retrieve names starting with that selected above alphabet..

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name_column like '[$_POST['alphabet_select']%';
```

With this approach, you can limit result set records to speed up loading name dropdown..

Comment: Hi, Thx , that is all done but i want the whole list to load fast . May be some kind of dynamic loading as we scroll down the dropdown, would help in this case

Answer (score 0):

**Load more than 5000 records in drop down list**

The good solution is not to load 5000 options into a DropDown via default dropdown or AJAX and any other method.

**Instead**

```
<select>
  <option value="Carvolvo"> Car Volvo</option>
  <option value="Samya">Samya</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Have you heard about the : https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage